# Реализуйте функцию, используя библиотеку math (python)

Tags: python

[image: Надо реализовать данную функцию]

```
def custom_function_1(x, n):
        res = 0
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
         res += (math.pow(n + 2, x) + math.log10(x)) / (math.pow(x, 2) + 4 * n)
        return res
        pass
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать данную функцию. У меня выдает ошибку AssertionError

Comment: Ну вроде бы символ `Π` обозначает умножение, а я в коде вижу почему-то сумму

Comment: `У меня выдает ошибку AssertionError` - Ваша проблема не воспроизводится, код работает нормально

Comment: @andreymal не знала, что это умножение, сейчас попробую исправить, спасибо

Comment: У вас в функции натуральный логарифм, а в коде почему-то логарифм по основанию 10

Comment: Написать в коде натуральный логарифм

Comment: https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-math.html

Comment: @T0xee.n17 спасибо за подсказку, не заметила этого, сейчас попытаюсь исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def custom_function_1(x, n):
    res = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
      res *= (math.pow(n + 2, x) + math.log1p(x)) / (math.pow(x, 2) + 4 * n)
    return res
```

Изменения:
`math.log10` -> `math.log1p` (натуральный логарифм)
`res +=` -> `res *=` (перемножение вместо сложения)
`res = 0` -> `res = 1`

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: Если мой ответ помог вам, отметьте его как принятый

Comment: res *= (math.pow(i + 2, x) + math.log1p(x)) / (math.pow(x, 2) + 4 * i) вот так надо подправить и все

Comment: Не уверен, в формуле очень странно написано - и итератор и максимальное значение задано одной буквой - тск не делают. Поэтому я и решил что это просто сумма

Comment: это моя ошибка, а так ваш алгоритм правильный, спасибо вам еще раз за помощь